# How to rewrite printf into cout

Tags: c++

I have a problem. I can write a printf with my code, but i have to write it in cout and i really have no idea how can i do. I tried with setprecision (3 + 1) etc. but it didn't work i have values from space. Can someone help me?

the printf with which i have problem looks:

```
printf("%.3f\t%.3f\t%.3f\t%.3f\t%.3f\n", i, cos(i), (i+1.0)/(i*i+1.0), exp(i), 1.0/exp(i))
```

I tried this, I'm expecting a tip.

```
cout << setprecision(3+1) << i <<  setprecision(3+1) << cos(i) << setprecision(3+1) << (i+1.0)/(i*i+1.0) << setprecision(3+1) << exp(i << setprecision(3+1) << 1.0/exp(i) << endl;
```

and whole code looks:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   float    xp = 0;
   float    xk = 0;
   float    dx = 0;

   cout << "enter the initial x, final x and difference: " << endl;
   cin >> xp >> xk >> dx;

   cout << "x\t\tcos(x)\t(x+1)(x*x+1)\texp(x)\t1/exp(x)\n";
   for(float i = xp; i <= xk; i = i + dx)
   {
       //*printf("%.3f\t%.3f\t%.3f\t%.3f\t%.3f\n", i, cos(i), (i+1.0)/(i*i+1.0), exp(i), 1.0/exp(i));//
   }


   return 0;
}
```

Im expecting https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mf5qu.jpg
Im getting https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL8yb.jpg

Comment: What did you try?  What were you expecting and what did you get?

Comment: You should [edit] that into the question

Comment: What @NathanOliver means is for you to state what output you received and what you _expected for the output_ (i.e., how is it different from what you expected?).

Comment: Im expecting http://imgur.com/BVGZstt
Im getting http://imgur.com/uDvZp82
or http://imgur.com/BVEaHV8 for this       cout << i << "     " << cos(i) << "     " << (i+1)/(i*i+1) << "     " << exp(i) << "     " << 1/exp(i) << "     " << endl;

Comment: you missed outputing a tab between each computation or item. "cout << '\t'"

Answer (score 2):

To set precision, use `setprecision(3)` and use `fixed` to print extra `0` after decimal

```
cout << setprecision(3)  << fixed << i << "\t"<<  cos(i) << "\t"<<  (i+1.0)/(i*i+1.0) << "\t"<<  exp(i) << "\t"<< 1.0/exp(i) << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

You forget the tabs, edit your C++ code like this :

```
cout << setprecision(3+1) << i << '\t' <<  setprecision(3+1) << cos(i) << '\t' << setprecision(3+1) << (i+1.0)/(i*i+1.0) << '\t' << setprecision(3+1) << exp(i) << '\t' << setprecision(3+1) << 1.0/exp(i) << endl;
```